# Understanding the Java classes called from the logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have an interesting question that is I am presently working on a Java project which consists of several Java classes and Spring Hibernate combination. This project was being built by lots of developers who worked earlier than me, and now in order to understand
it I have to debug the project and cross check the logs to understand the flow. In logs.properties I found this setting at the root level:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CONSOLE
```

which clearly states that highest priority is given to ERROR level now my query is that I set it to this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,ERROR,CONSOLE
```

to put DEBUG ahead in order to increase the priority of DEBUG since I want to check in the logs which Java classes are called one after the other in the background as the flow is moving. I have checked in Java classes that log.debug statements are there. Is this all correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you understand what `log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CONSOLE` means.  It says nothing about PRIORITY.  In fact, priority has no meaning in the context of level.  In fact, what it says is that the logging LEVEL for the root logger (which is inherited all loggers) is "ERROR"; i.e. by default, only ERROR and higher level (i.e. more severe) log events will be processed.  (It also attached the "CONSOLE" appender to the root logger ...)

So when you write `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,ERROR,CONSOLE`, it doesn't actually make sense.  You are saying that the LEVEL is both DEBUG and ERROR ... but it can't be both.  (What actually happens is anyone's guess ... because it is outside of the spec.)

---

As to what you are *trying* to do:

> ... is keeping DEBUG ahead in order to increase the priority of DEBUG , since i want to check in the logs that which java classes are called one after the other in the background as the flow is moving and i have checked in java classes that log.debug statements are there.

I have great difficulty in understanding what that "sentence" mean.  But if you are trying to affect the order in which log events appear in the logs, you are out of luck.  They appear in (roughly) the order in which the `Logger` calls were made, and (AFAIK) there is nothing you can do to change the order.

(AFAIK, the log event ordering is "best effort".  Guaranteeing strict temporal ordering would entail a concurrency bottleneck, and people don't like it when logging unduly affects application throughput.)

Comment: Thanks a lot so can you please advise what I should do to set the level to DEBUG mode as I want to study how classes are being called one after the other

Comment: Thanks basically i want to set the DEBUG level as default ..!

Comment: `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CONSOLE`